# Capturing cassandra cql metrics from spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, prometheus, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

I want to capture the db query metrics from springboot cassandra application and expose to prometheus endpoint.

Already have implemenatation for springboot+ postgres and its working with r2dbc-proxy. since r2dbc not providing support for cassandra. looking for any sample implementation.

After edited code for below comment:

```
    String contactPoint = System.getProperty("contactPoint", "127.0.0.1");
    // init default prometheus stuff
    DefaultExports.initialize();
    // setup Prometheus HTTP server
    Optional<HTTPServer> prometheusServer = Optional.empty();
    try {
        prometheusServer = Optional.of(new HTTPServer(Integer.getInteger("prometheusPort", 9095)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception when creating HTTP server for Prometheus: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPointsWithPorts(new InetSocketAddress(contactPoint, 9042))
            .withoutJMXReporting()
            .build();

    try (Session session = cluster.connect()) {
        MetricRegistry myRegistry = new MetricRegistry();
        myRegistry.registerAll(cluster.getMetrics().getRegistry());
        CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry.register(new DropwizardExports(myRegistry));

        session.execute("create keyspace if not exists test with replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};");
        session.execute("create table if not exists test.abc (id int, t1 text, t2 text, primary key (id, t1));");
        session.execute("truncate test.abc;");

    }
    catch(IllegalStateException ex){
        System.out.println("metric registry fails to configure!!!!!");
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If using micrometer

1. add dependency `com.datastax.oss:java-driver-metrics-micrometer`
2. Create CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer and register MeterRegistry (io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry) bean using `withMetricRegistry` method.
3. Create DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer with used metrics (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62940370/12584290)

Answer (score 0):

DataStax Java driver exposes metrics via Dropwizard Metrics library ([driver version 3.x](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/metrics/), [driver version 4.x](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.5/manual/core/metrics/)) that could be exposed as Prometheus endpoint using via standard Prometheus libraries, like `io.prometheus.simpleclient_dropwizard` that is part of [Prometheus Java client library](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java).

Here is an [example for driver version 4.x](https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/metrics-to-prometheus-java), but with small modification it could work with 3.x as well. The main part is following:

```java
MetricRegistry registry = session.getMetrics()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Metrics are disabled"))
        .getRegistry();
CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry.register(new DropwizardExports(registry));
```

the rest is just creating session, exposing metrics via HTTP, etc.

Comment: Since our application follows with driver version 3.x . creating cqlsession is making some difficult. I've referred this https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/metrics-to-prometheus-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/MetricsWithPrometheus.java.  so do you have idea of how to create cqlsession in driver version 3.x

Comment: As I wrote, this example is for version 4.x. For version 3.x, just follow corresponding documentation, although you should have `Cluster` object created by Spring Boot - either directly, or via `Session.getCluster()`.  And then call `getMetrics()` on that Cluster object.

Comment: Am able to get the metrics exposed in prometheusserver as you have described. But the thing is when am hitting any api through postman then i want to capture the query executed from application. that type of information not able to get it. Actually Looking for a query level metrics from it.

Comment: please update your question with more details what kind of information you're looking for...

Comment: Yeah. I need to capture the cql query level information and the time it takes to execute it. instead am getting details like below.# HELP requests Generated from Dropwizard metric import (metric=requests, type=com.codahale.metrics.Timer)
# TYPE requests summary
requests{quantile="0.5",} 0.005036901000000001
requests{quantile="0.75",} 0.4274601
requests{quantile="0.95",} 0.4274601
requests{quantile="0.98",} 0.4274601
requests{quantile="0.99",} 0.4274601
requests{quantile="0.999",} 0.4274601
requests_count 3.0

Comment: why it doesn't enough for you? documentation says that is: "the mean, min and max latencies, as well as latency at a given percentile."

Comment: I have updated the code also. May be if anything I've done wrong.  and my interpretation is to expose information like below.       for example:  cql_query_seconds_count (uri="api/firstapi", query="select * from eample_table where column1= ?") like wise i need it.

Comment: You can theoretically use QueryLogger (https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/logging/#logging-query-latencies) and populate MetricRegistry with collected data. I don't have examples for that

Comment: Any idea on how to export QueryLogger information to dropwizard export. since I can able to see the logs at the Intellij IDE. but not able to export