# How to enable Cassandra CqlSession Metrics in springbootapplication

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I want to enable cassandra cqlsession metrics. when trying to register the cqlsession metrics it provides optional.empty() in springboot application. Here am using cassandra datastax java driver 4.6.

Here is my code:

```
@Autowired
private CqlSession cqlsession;

MetricRegistry metricRegistry = cqlsession.getMetrics()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("not able to get metrics"))
            .getRegistry();
```

Throwing IllegalArgumentException Error.

when referring the official docs for cassandra datastax (https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.6/manual/core/metrics/#configuration). the same set of conf files added to the project not resoles the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved this with following approach:

The configuration class

```
import static com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.config.DefaultDriverOption.METRICS_NODE_ENABLED;
import static com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.config.DefaultDriverOption.METRICS_SESSION_ENABLED;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CassandraProperties.class)
public class CassandraMetricsConfig {

    @Bean
    DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer configLoaderBuilderCustomizer(CassandraProperties cassandraProperties) {
        return builder -> {
            builder.withStringList(METRICS_SESSION_ENABLED, cassandraProperties.getSessionMetrics());
            builder.withStringList(METRICS_NODE_ENABLED, cassandraProperties.getNodeMetrics());
        };
    }
}
```

The property class

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cassandra")
@Data
public class CassandraProperties {

    @NotNull
    private List<String> sessionMetrics = new ArrayList<>();

    @NotNull
    private List<String> nodeMetrics = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

application.yml

```
cassandra:
  session-metrics:
    - bytes-sent
    - connected-nodes
    ...
  node-metrics:
    - pool.open-connections
    - pool.in-flight
    ...
```

Note this approach works only for metrics which do not require an additional configuration like cql-requests. If you want to monitor the cql-requests you have to extend the example to configure the required properties.